# How to access MainWindow.Widget from a subclass?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 3 Qlabels: label1, label2 and label3.

My idea is this: when mouse hover label1 or label2, label3.text will show 'mouse on label1' or 'mouse on label2' according to which label got mouse hovered.

I created a subclass 'CustomLabel' for label1 and label2, where I define the enterEvent function.

The problem is that I can't access label3 from that class.

MainWindow.ui.label3 is impossible to reach!

Here is the code, everything is working except that one line of code where I didnt manage to get access to label3.

I am a very beginner so probably I am missing something very simple.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(688, 446)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label1 = CustomLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 110, 121, 31))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        self.label2 = CustomLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 110, 121, 31))
        self.label2.setObjectName("label2")
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 280, 121, 31))
        self.label3.setObjectName("label3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Label1"))
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Label2"))
        self.label3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Label3"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class CustomLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self,texte):
        Custom_font = QtGui.QFont()
        Custom_font.setPointSize(14)
        super(CustomLabel,self).__init__(texte)
        self.setFont(Custom_font)

    def enterEvent(self,e):
        print('here is ',self.text())
        MainWindow.ui.label3.setText('mouse on ', self.text)   # Error on this line, 'MainWindow' has no attribute ui
        #MainWindow.label3.setText('mouse on ', self.text)       # Error here too, 'MainWindow' has no attribute label3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MainWindow.ui.label3 is impossible to reach" because `label3` does not exist, nor does `ui`.

`MainWindow` is a [*class*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), a "template" for an *instance*.

So, the `MainWindow` *class* object has no attribute called `ui` (therefore, no `ui.label3` also), *but* the `mainWindow` *instance* you create near the end of your code does.

To achieve what you want, there are at least two methods.

### Use signals/slots to allow communication between the instances

Create a signal for the CustomLabel class, and emit it whenever the mouse enters it; then connect that signal from the main window:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.label1.entered.connect(self.labelEntered)
        self.ui.label2.entered.connect(self.labelEntered)

    def labelEntered(self, label):
        self.ui.label3.setText('mouse on {}'.format(label.text()))


class CustomLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    entered = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self,texte):
        Custom_font = QtGui.QFont()
        Custom_font.setPointSize(14)
        super(CustomLabel,self).__init__(texte)
        self.setFont(Custom_font)

    def enterEvent(self,e):
        self.entered.emit(self)
```

### Use an event filter to catch events

In this case, we [install an event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the widgets we want to watch for events, and if that event is a mouse enter one, we'll update the third label accordingly:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.label1.installEventFilter(self)
        self.ui.label2.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if isinstance(source, CustomLabel) and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
            # the "source" of the event is one of our custom labels, and the event
            # type is an "Enter" one, so let's update the other label
            self.ui.label3.setText('mouse on {}'.format(source.text()))
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

As a side note, it seems that you're trying to edit the contents of a file generated from `pyuic` (or, at least, you're probably trying to mimick their behavior). This is something that should never be done, as those files are only meant to be used as imported modules in your actual program (and their mimicking their behavior is not the best way to create your GUI from code).
Read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand the correct ways to use files created by Designer.
If you need to extend the default Qt widgets by subclassing and you need to use those classes on Designer, do some research about using "promoted widgets".